# Sequential Transformation with fix Chunk Sizes in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, transformation, sequential

edit: see [Loop 5 records at a time and assign it to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016596/loop-5-records-at-a-time-and-assign-it-to-variable) as pointed out in the comments.

Please dont delete this question, as the formulation is with entirely different words!

---

savvy people

I do not know how to proceed with my problem, where I need to transform a large row set (by using an R-Script) in chunks.

Let's assume I have created a temporary table `RAW_DATA_delta` containing the new incoming raw data that has not been transformed yet and is thus not yet present in the `TRANSFORMED_DATA`

The `RAW_DATA_delta` may contain 10M new rows on each incoming data load, but the `RAW_TRANSFORMATION`-SSIS task cannot take more than 1M rows at once or else it crashes (due to being a R-Script)

Now I would like a Loop Container in which I get always 1M row and run the `RAW_TRANSFORMATION`-Task, but that's where I don't know how to proceed. The transformations need to run *sequentially*, thus conditional split is unusable. It is not clear to me if I can use the for/foreach-Tasks, since I want to split in x/1M loops without previous knowledge how many..

Can somebody get me started here? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016596/loop-5-records-at-a-time-and-assign-it-to-variable try this link

Comment: Thank you @RedDevil. How can I mark my question as duplicate?